# Generate balanced parentheses in java

Tags: java, algorithm

The question is:
Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.

For example, given n = 3, a solution set is:

"((()))", "(()())", "(())()", "()(())", "()()()"

I used to solve this problem using string as following codes:

```
public class Solution {
public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    //StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    generate(n, 0, 0, "", result);
    return result;
}
public void generate(int n, int left, int right, String s, ArrayList<String> result){

    //left is num of '(' and right is num of ')'
    if(left < right){
        return;
    }
    if(left == n && right == n){
        result.add(s);
        return;
    }
    if(left == n){
        //add ')' only.
        generate(n, left, right + 1, s + ")", result);
        return;
    }
    generate(n, left + 1, right, s + "(", result);
    generate(n, left, right + 1, s + ")", result);
    }
}
```

Now I want to solve this problem using StringBuilder, the code is like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class generateParentheses {
public static ArrayList<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    generate(n, 0, 0, result, sb);
    return result;
}

public static void generate(int n, int left, int right, ArrayList<String> result,
        StringBuilder sb) {

    if (left < right) {
        return;
    }
    if (left == n && right == n) {
        result.add(sb.toString());
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        return;
    }
    if (left == n) {
        generate(n, left, right + 1, result, sb.append(')'));
        return;
    }
    generate(n, left + 1, right, result, sb.append('('));
    //sb.delete(sb.length(), sb.length() + 1);
    generate(n, left, right + 1, result, sb.append(')'));
    //sb.delete(sb.length(), sb.length() + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(generateParenthesis(4));
    }
}
```

The result is not what I want:
(((()))), (((()))))())), (((()))))())))()), (((()))))())))()))(), (((()))))())))()))()))(())), (((()))))())))()))()))(())))()).........

Is there anyone tell me what is the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please be more specific. Don't just past a line of parens and expect us to count them and compare it to your recursive algo. IOW, what does - "The result is not what I want" actually mean?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code and see why paths you expect to take to produce certain outputs are not being made? I'd imagine you would find out pretty soon what wrong logic or missing logic you have. If you did debug already, perhaps you have a more specific question, like why is this if statement not helping create this pattern of output given this series of recursive calls etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ware close. Your mistakes ware:

- trying to reset `sb` instead of removing only its last character
- way you want to reset `sb`:

  - by using `sb = new StringBuilder();` you are reassigning `sb` which is local variable of **current** method, not variable of method which invoked it (Java is not pass-by-reference but pass-by-value).
  - your almost correct attempt ware commented `sb.delete(sb.length(), sb.length() + 1);` but here you are actually trying to remove characters starting from position `sb.length()`, but just like arrays indexes of character in StringBuilder are from `0` till `sb.length() - 1` so is trying to remove one character after last character which effectively can't remove anything.

    What you needed here is

    ```
    sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
    ```

    or more readable

    ```
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    ```

    but probably best approach in terms of performance `setLength` (described at bottom of answer)

    ```
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
    ```
- your logic of **when** to remove characters from StringBuilder is also flawed

  - you are doing it only in one place which ends (backtracks) recursive calls: after finding correct results. But what about other cases like `if (left < right)` or ***most importantly, if method will end normally*** like

    ```
    generate(3, 1, 1, ')');
    generate(3, 1, 2, ')');//here we stop and backtrack
    ```

    Here `generate(3, 1, 2, ')');` ends and removes last character from `sb`, but shouldn't previous method `generate(3, 1, 1, ')')` also remove its own `)` added to StringBuilder?

  In other words you shouldn't remove last character only at end of successful condition in recursive call, but after each recursive call, to make sure that method will also remove character it adds.

So change your code to something like

```
public static void generate(int n, int left, int right, ArrayList<String> result,
        StringBuilder sb) {

    if (left < right) {
        return;
    }
    if (left == n && right == n) {
        result.add(sb.toString());
        return;
    }
    if (left == n) {
        generate(n, left, right + 1, result, sb.append(')'));
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);// <--
        return;
    }
    generate(n, left + 1, right, result, sb.append('('));
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);// <--
    generate(n, left, right + 1, result, sb.append(')'));
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);// <--
}
```

or try writing something probably more readable like

```
public static void generate(int maxLength, int left, int right,
        ArrayList<String> result, StringBuilder sb) {
    if (left + right == maxLength) {
        if (left == right)
            result.add(sb.toString());
    } else if (left >= right) {
        generate(maxLength, left + 1, right, result, sb.append('('));
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

        generate(maxLength, left, right + 1, result, sb.append(')'));
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

but while invoking you would need to set `maxLength` as `2*n` since it is the max length StringBuilder should contain, so you would also have to change `generateParenthesis(int n)` to:

```
public static ArrayList<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 * n);

    generate(2 * n, 0, 0, result, sb);
    //       ^^^^^
    return result;
}
```

---

**Farther improvement:**

If you are aiming for performance then you probably don't want to use `delete` or `deleteCharAt` because each time it creates new array and fills it with copy of values from without ones you don't want.

Instead you can use `setLength` method. If you will pass value which is smaller than number of currently stored characters it will set `count` to value passed in this method, which will effectively make characters after them irrelevant. In other words this characters will be no longer used in for instance `toString()` even if they will be still in StringBuilder buffer array.

Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");  // 1
sb.setLength(2);                              // 2
System.out.println(sb);                       // 3
sb.append('d');                               // 4
System.out.println(sb);                       // 5
```

- In line 1 `StringBuilder` will allocate array for at least `3` characters (by default it uses `str.length() + 16` to determine size of buffered array of characters it will store for now) and will place there characters from passed String, so it will contain

  ```
  ['a', 'b', 'c', '\0', '\0', ... , '\0']
                   ^^^ - it will put next character here
  ```

  Index of position where next character should be placed is stored in `count` field and for now it is equal to `3`.
- In line 2 value of `count` will be set to `2`, but our array will not be changed so it will still look like

  ```
  ['a', 'b', 'c', '\0', '\0', ... , '\0']
             ^^^ - it will put next character here
  ```
- In line 3 new String will be created and printed, but it will be filled only with characters placed before index stored in `count`, which means that it will contain only `a` and `b` (array will still be unchanged).
- In line 4 you will add new character to buffer and it will be placed after "important" characters. Since number of important characters is stored in `count` field (and they are placed at beginning of array), next irrelevant character must be at position pointed by `count`, which means `d` will be placed at position with index `2` which means now array will look like

  ```
  ['a', 'b', 'd', '\0', '\0', ... , '\0']
                   ^^^ - it will put next character here
  ```

  and value of `count` will be incremented (we added only one character so `count` will now become `3`).
- In line 5 we will create and print string containing first `3` characters from array used by `StringBuilder` so we will see `abd`.

Comment: WOW, really thanks a lot, Pshemo! Your answer helps me a lot!

Comment: @tonymiao You are welcome, anyway I added improvement if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

After carefully debuting this program, I found out the problem. The correct code is listed as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class generateParentheses {
    public static ArrayList<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    generate(n, 0, 0, result, sb);
    return result;
}

public static void generate(int n, int left, int right, ArrayList<String> result,
        StringBuilder sb) {

    if (left < right) {
        return;
    }
    if (left == n && right == n) {
        result.add(sb.toString());
        //sb.delete(0,sb.length());
        return;
    }
    if (left == n) {
        generate(n, left, right + 1, result, sb.append(')'));
        //delete current ')'.
        sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
        return;
    }

    generate(n, left + 1, right, result, sb.append('('));
    //delete current '(' after you finish using it for next recursion.
    sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
    generate(n, left, right + 1, result, sb.append(')'));
    //same as above here.
    sb.delete(sb.length() - 1, sb.length());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(generateParenthesis(4));


    }

}
```

And the result is:
(((()))), ((()())), ((())()), ((()))(), (()(())), (()()()), (()())(), (())(()), (())()(), ()((())), ()(()()), ()(())(), ()()(()), ()()()()

Answer (score 0):

The combination of a parameter, assigment and return:

```
..., StringBuilder sb,...
    //...
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    return sb;
```

does not make sense, because the parameter is passed in by value, i.e., sb is a local variable the change of which has no effect in the calling environment.

If you want to clear the StringBuilder, there is method sb.delete( start, end ) that will truly affect the object referenced via sb.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Another much simpler way of doing this. 
Here, i am trying for a recursive solution where the recursive function adds balanced parentheses in 3 ways: "()"+result and result+"()" and "("+result+")" for each item in HashSet returned by the function it calls then put them in a HashSet to remove duplicates.

```
     import java.util.HashSet;
     import java.util.Set;

     public class BalancedParanthesis {
       public static void main(String args[]){
         int noOfBrackets = 3;
         HashSet<String> hs=new HashSet(generate(noOfBrackets));
         System.out.println(hs);
         }
         public static HashSet<String> generate(int in)
         {
          HashSet<String> hs= new HashSet<String>();
          if(in ==1)
         {
        hs.add("()");
        return hs;
         }
        else{
           Set<String> ab=generate(in-1);
           for(String each:ab)
            {
            hs.add("("+each+")");
            hs.add("()"+each);
            hs.add(each+"()");
            }
        return hs;
         }
        }
       }
```

Comment: Please add a little more context to what exactly you're doing here.

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain what i have done.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is inefficient. Here is a better approach. We make an effective brute force over the 2^N possible bracket permutations with heavy pruning(we quit the recursion immediately if there is no possible valid solution for the current parameters).
Here's the code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string result;
vector<string> solutions;
int N = 10;
void generateBrackets(int pos, int balance)
{
    if(balance > N-pos) return;
    if(pos == N)
    {
        //we have a valid solution
        //generate substring from 0 to N-1
        //and push it to the vector
        string currentSolution;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            currentSolution.push_back(result[i]);
        }
        solutions.push_back(currentSolution);
        return;
    }
    result[pos] = '(';
    generateBrackets(pos+1, balance+1);
    if(balance > 0)
    {
        result[pos] = ')';
        generateBrackets(pos+1, balance-1);
    }
}
int main()
{
    result.assign(N, 'a');
    generateBrackets(0, 0);
    cout<<"Printing solutions:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < solutions.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<solutions[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some clarifications: pos marks the current position in the bracket solution we are generating. If we reach position N (that means the solution is valid) we have a valid solution in the `string result` variable and we simple push it in the vector with the valid solutions. Now for what we use balance you may ask. We make the observation that in order a bracket permutation to be valid, at any time at any given position the count of the '(' from the start must be greater than the count of the ')'s and with balance we measure their difference, so me put a ')' at a given position only if the balance > 0.

Comment: But he's not passing a "whole List." He's passing a reference to a List, which is a negligible cost. And posting a c++ solution doesn't really help with fixing a Java program.

Comment: Kindly delete the claim that "passing a whole List as a parameter" is inefficient. The List is not copied (which might cause some overhead) - only a reference is passed.

Comment: Also, even when a large data structure *is indeed copied*, it will *not* cause stackoverflow; it *may* cause OutOfMemory. Stack Overflow is usually caused by a recursive call going down too many levels.

Comment: And OP would like to have it in Java, so please comply or abstain. Thank you.

Comment: Some valid points made. Well, I believe it won't be a problem for him to translate it to Java, the algorithm is important here.

Comment: Hi, I need a java solution. Not C++ solution. Thank you.