# Balanced Parentheses

Tags: algorithm, parentheses, catalan

I was wondering if anyone can answer me which is number of results generated in the backtracking solution for the next problem:

Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.

For example, given n = 3, a solution set is:

"((()))", "(()())", "(())()", "()(())", "()()()"

There is a related post in stackoverflow: [Generate balanced parentheses in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704170/generate-balanced-parentheses-in-java)

My doubt if that if there is a formula that can give me the number of valid parentheses I can generate before compute them.
for example:
- f(n):
- f(1) = 1
- f(2) = 2
- f(3) = 5
and so on..

Thank you.

Comment: Sure looks like it, which makes the "show us what you've tried" part pretty pertinent

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a formula for combinatorics, and better asked at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number expressions containing n pairs of parentheses which are correctly matched can be calculated via Catalan numbers. Quoting the relevant [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) from Wikipedia:

> There are many counting problems in combinatorics whose solution is given by the Catalan numbers … Cn is the number of Dyck words of length 2n. A Dyck word is a string consisting of n X's and n Y's such that no initial segment of the string has more Y's than X's … Re-interpreting the symbol X as an open parenthesis and Y as a close parenthesis, Cn counts the number of expressions containing n pairs of parentheses which are correctly matched.

The nth Catalan number is given directly in terms of binomial coefficients by:

[image: The nth Catalan number, image taken from Wikipedia]

Comment: Thank you! In fact I was practicing algorithms for a programming interview, and I had the doubt when I wrote the algorithm.